# The bootstrap feature "row" makes horizontal columns in my project

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2017

I am making a website using visual studio in 2017. I installed the bootstrap

library: twitter-bootstrap@4.3.1

When doing a simple container, row, col the content is displayed vertically and not in columns across the screen.

Should appear:

Hello                          it                                  wont work

When I run it in visual studio:

Hello

It

won't work

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 panel" style="background-color: red">
            Hello</div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 panel" style="background-color: yellow">
            it</div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 panel" style="background-color: pink">
            Wont work</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: there is no more `xs` it should only be `col-4` or simply `col` (doc: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: @temaniAfif it still won't work, just puts it in a vertical list, makes no sense

Comment: in all the cases, your code is wrong and you need to correct the classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with my Layout View. Thank you and sorry for the bother.

Answer (score 0):

Check your CSS if there are no other line inheriting the code.

Comment: <style>
        body {
            padding: 0px;
            background-image: url('images/background.jpg');
            height: 500px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size:cover;
        }
    </style>

Comment: I have only that else for a background

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion instead of using Bootstrap to align your items horizontally use the css.

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="one panel" style="background-color: red">
            Hello</div>
            <div class="two panel" style="background-color: yellow">
            it</div>
            <div class="three panel" style="background-color: pink">
            will work</div>

    </div>
</body>
```

css

```
panel{
width: 33%;
}
```

and if you want to only make it a column in a small view port,use media queries.

hope it helps..